# Resultant Video is always longer than input audio, even though I am using -shortest option of ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following command to make a video from a single image;

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i MyInputImage.png -i MyInputSound.m4a ^
  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac ^
  -shortest MyOutputVideo.mp4
```

Note that I have used the ***-shortest*** option;

But I have noticed my resulting video IS ALWAYS 2 seconds longer than my AUDIO length. Why ?

For example, if audio=5 secs, output vid lenght is 7 secs; if audio=9 secs, output video is 11 seconds long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an imperfect implementation of -shortest, now rectified in version 5.0. So, upgrade.

---

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i MyInputImage.png -t 2 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p ^
   imagevideo.mp4

ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i imagevideo.mp4 -i MyInputSound.m4a ^
   -c copy -shortest MyOutputVideo.mp4
```

Comment: "ffmpeg -version" does not show version? ffmpeg version 2022-05-19-git-dd99d34d67-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 11.3.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl
libavutil      57. 24.101 / 57. 24.101
libavcodec     59. 28.100 / 59. 28.100
libavformat    59. 24.100 / 59. 24.100
libavdevice    59.  6.100 / 59.  6.100
libavfilter     8. 38.100 /  8. 38.100
libswscale      6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100
libswresample   4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
libpostproc    56.  5.100 / 56.  5.100

Comment: That's a git build from 2022-05-19 so newer than 5.0 which was released on 2022-01-14

Comment: FYI I accepted your answer, but It never resolved the issue, I just ignored the BUGGY shortest cmd; Today I tried again, my audio is 18 secs long, but the video is 20 secs long (exactly as per my original question); And I used the build exactly as you see in my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, so I rechecked and it seems the bug fix only works for streamcopy. Use commands in answer edit.

Comment: I don't understand your edited answer, you are doing a short video for 2 secs (-t 2) and then you are adding the sound and using -shortest. So the final output will always be 2 secs ? (even if the sound is longer)

Comment: Edited to add looping.

Comment: Ok makes sense now; I may as well just use my original question, and instead of using -shortest, I will use -t secs (because I already know the length of my audio)

Comment: You can still use -shortest in your original cmd but add `-fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 200M`